# Best way to compare date in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using date in where clause in Entity Framework and getting following error:

[image]

It is due to the below code:

```
var entity = dbContext.MyTable
                      .Where(w => w.PId = 3 && w.CreatedOn.Date == mydate.Date)
                      .First();
```

If I convert data into list using `.ToList()`, then compare to date, it will work fine but if I do so then it will pull data first into code then filter it out. Please help me out with this issue. Currently I am using a stored procedure to resolve the issue but really want this to work.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) canonical function like this

```
var entity = dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(w => w.PId == 3 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(w.CreatedOn) == mydate.Date)
    .First();
```

Comment: You need to use it on `mydate` too or assign `mydate.Date` to another variable and use that in the Linq query.

Comment: @juharr Just checked with EF6, no need to use variable for the constant expression `myDate.Date`

Comment: Thanks a lot @IvanStoev. Your help is really appreciated and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I ended up doing Date search when I had to consider time (Hour and Minutes portion) also

```
var entity = dbContext.MyTable
                      .Where(
                    x => x.CreatedOn.Year == mydate.Year
                    && x.CreatedOn.Month == mydate.Month
                    && x.CreatedOn.Day == mydatee.Day
                    && x.CreatedOn.Hour == mydate.Hour
                    && x.CreatedOn.Minute== mydate.Minute
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

you cannot compare dates directly by using `.Date` for this you have to use `DbFunctions` or `EntityFunctions`.

I prefer to use `DbFunctions`

You can use it as given below:

```
var entity = dbContext.MyTable
                  .Where(w => w.PId = 3 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(w.CreatedOn) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(mydate))
                  .First();
```

Comment: FYI: The `EntityFunctions` class is obsolet and has been replaced by `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions`.

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't currently support translating all granular operations on objects in LINQ to an SQL query (which is what happens prior to that ToList() operation). Some things are (such as .Contains() on primitive collections).  But not all things.

So, while you may have expected the query to translate to various "DATEPART" comparisons in the SQL statement, it's just not supported.  You have to change your LINQ to accommodate it a bit.

One way is to evaluate the 24-hour range. This will work on either side of the ToList():

```
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(mydate.Date.Year, mydate.Date.Month, mydate.Date.Second);
DateTime maxDate = minDate.AddSeconds(86399);

var entity = dbContext.MyTable
                      .Where(w => w.PId = 3 && w.CreatedOn >= minDate && w.CreatedOn <= maxDate).First();
```