# Entity Framework refusing Date comparison The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to retrieve all the records that match today's date, but I get this exception when I run

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

I tried this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14601775/13211556

but no effect same exception, also tried to change the column in the DB to Date only instead of DateTime.

here is the code:

```
List<int> Ids = context.Record
            .Where(rec => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(rec.Date.Date) == date)
            .Select(rec => rec.Id)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Does your date column allow Nulls?

Comment: try this `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(rec.Date?.Date)`

Comment: @djv No, it doesn't

Comment: @Hossein Giving error on the operator '?'

Comment: The `?` relied on my question being answered yes :)

Comment: So I assume you have seen answers such as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40651639/832052 , could you try using the DbFunctions.TruncateTime on `date` as well?

Comment: It worked after allowing Nulls thanks :)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you change your data model. Only if it is appropriate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance you have to use comparison operators. You have `date` without time, so add one day and write appropriate LINQ query.

```cs
var nextDay = date.AddDays(1);

List<int> Ids = context.Record
            .Where(rec => rec.Date >= date && rec.Date < nextDay)
            .Select(rec => rec.Id)
            .ToList();
```

Only in this case indexes

Comment: This only works if the column is nullable what if I want it not nullable

Comment: Sorry, removed not needed `.Date` suffix.